# Como verificar se a classe foi instancia através do DataProvider utilizando PHP Unit

Tags: php, testcase, phpunit

Alguém poderia fazer um exemplo? Considerando a minha classe abaixo:

```
class MinhaClasse
{

    private $param;

    public function __construct(array $params = []) {
       
      $this->param = $params;
    
    }

}
```

Tenho a minha classe de teste:

```
require_once "MinhaClasse.php";

class MinhaClasseTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{

    /**
     * @dataProvider additionProvider
     */
  
    public function additionProvider()
    {
        return array(
          array('?????', null, null),
          array(0, 1, 1),
          array(1, 0, 1),
          array(1, 1, 3)
        );
    }

    public function testShouldMyClassIsInstantiate($instance, $value, $expected)
    {
        $this->assertEquals($expected, $value);
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acabei chegando na solução sozinho, para testar uma instância basta fazer o seguinte, conforme está descrito na documentação: https://phpunit.de/manual/current/pt_br/appendixes.assertions.html#appendixes.assertions.assertInstanceOf

```
require_once "MinhaClasse.php";

class MinhaClasseTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    /**
     * @dataProvider additionProvider
     */
    public function additionProvider()
    {
        return array(
          array('MinhaClasse', new MinhaClasse()),
        );
    }

    public function testShouldMyClassIsInstantiate($expected, $instance)
    {
      $this->assertInstanceOf($expected, $instance,'The Class "{$expected}" can\'t be instantiated'); 
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Um método `DataProvider` retorna um array de arrays ou um objeto que implementa a interface `Iterator`. O método de teste será chamado com o conteúdo da matriz e seus argumentos.

Alguns pontos-chave usando DataProvider:

- Método DataProvider deve ser público.
- DataProvider retornará um `array` de dados.
- Use a anotação de teste(@dataProvider) para declarar seu método dataProvider.

É realmente muito simples de usar dataProvider. Primeiro vamos criar um novo método público, que retorna uma matriz de conjunto de dados como argumentos do método de teste. Então nós adicionamos uma anotação ao método de teste para dizer que `PHPUnit` irá fornecer os argumentos.

```
  <?php
require 'Calculator.php';

class CalculatorTests extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    private $calculator;

    protected function setUp()
    {
        $this->calculator = new Calculator();
    }

    protected function tearDown()
    {
        $this->calculator = NULL;
    }

    public function addDataProvider() {
        return array(
            array(1,2,3),
            array(0,0,0),
            array(-1,-1,-2),
        );
    }

    /**
     * @dataProvider addDataProvider
     */
    public function testAdd($a, $b, $expected)
    {
        $result = $this->calculator->add($a, $b);
        $this->assertEquals($expected, $result);
    }

 }
```

[Fonte](http://www.startutorial.com/articles/view/phpunit-beginner-part-2-data-provider)

[Manual](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html)

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta @Lollipop, mas a minha dúvida não se trata de  como utilizar o dataProvider, o que preciso saber é como poderia fazer um teste que me responderia se a classe testada pelo dataProvider foi instanciada através do PHP Unit, talvez colocar algo como `instanceof` ...